# User is being logged out every time closing the app in ionic/angular

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework

I was asssigned with a work where the user supposed to be logged in if he close an app. one should be logged out only if user tap on "log out". I have tried to use the following code in app.component.ts but it is not giving the desired out put
Can anyone help in this?

```
      this.navCtrl.navigateRoot("/tabs/tabs/home");
    } else {
      this.navCtrl.navigateRoot("");
    }
```

here's authentrication.service.ts

```
import { Member } from "./../../interface/member";
import { Platform, NavController } from "@ionic/angular";
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { Storage } from "@ionic/storage";
import { BehaviorSubject } from "rxjs";
import { DataService } from "../data/data.service";
import { ObservablesService } from "../observable/observables.service";
import { SplashScreen } from "@ionic-native/splash-screen/ngx";
import { Badge } from "@ionic-native/badge/ngx";
import { ServerService } from "../server/server.service";

const TOKEN_KEY = "auth-token";

export interface OcOAuth {
  success: number;

  error: any;
  data: {
    access_token: string;
    expire_in: number;
    token_type: string;
  };
}
@Injectable({
  providedIn: "root",
})
export class AuthenticationService {
  authenticationState = new BehaviorSubject(false);

  constructor(
    private storage: Storage,
    private plt: Platform,
    private dataService: DataService,
    private observable: ObservablesService,
    private splashScreen: SplashScreen,
    private navCtrl: NavController,
    private badge: Badge,
    private server: ServerService
  ) {
    this.plt.ready().then(() => {
      this.checkToken();
    });

    this.observable.unread().subscribe((res) => {
      this.badge.set(res);
      console.log("observed unread", res);
    });
  }

  async checkToken() {
    await this.storage.get("member").then((res) => {
      if (res != null) {
        let token = res ? JSON.parse(res) : null;
        token = token["secret"] ? token["secret"] : null;
        if (token) {
          this.authenticationState.next(true);
          if (this.server.url != this.server.check_url) {
            this.navCtrl.navigateRoot("/tabs/tabs/home");
          }
          this.isLoggedIn();
        } else {
          this.authenticationState.next(false);
          this.navCtrl.navigateRoot("");
        }
      }
    });
  }

  login(data) {
    return this.storage.set(TOKEN_KEY, "Bearer 1234").then(() => {
      this.dataService.setStorageData("member", data);
      this.dataService.setData("member", data);

      console.log("Member data", data);
      this.observable.user.next(data.user);
      this.authenticationState.next(true);

      return true;
    });
  }

  isLoggedIn() {
    this.authenticationState.next(true);
    console.log("USER LOGGGED IN");

    return true;
  }

  logout() {
    return this.storage.remove("member").then(() => {
      this.badge.clear();
      this.authenticationState.next(false);
    });
  }

  isAuthenticated() {
    return this.authenticationState.value;
  }
}
```

auth.guard.ts

```
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { CanActivate, Router } from "@angular/router";
import { AuthenticationService } from "../services/authentication/authentication.service";
import { NavController } from "@ionic/angular";

@Injectable({
  providedIn: "root",
})
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {
  constructor(
    public auth: AuthenticationService,
    public router: Router,
    private navCtrl: NavController
  ) {}

  canActivate(): boolean {
    return this.auth.isAuthenticated();
  }
}
```

Comment: `this.authenticationState.value` returns `false` the first time, so if you have a logout based on that value, that would happen.

Comment: `authentication State = new BehaviorSubject(false)` - the initial value is declared as false and while user logout the `this.authentication State.value` supposed to return that I understand. But How can I change the isAutrhenticated value into true so that it doen not log out the user??

Comment: I don't even see at which point the user is being logged out?